# Editor fonts incorrectly shown by Pycharm (Jetbrains)

Tags: macos, fonts, editor, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm for many years. But suddenly Pycharm Editor's and Colsole's font begin to show fonts ugly. I've restarted Mac, it worked good for 10 minutes, then again ugly fonts. And now restart doesn't help too. What can be problem?

I've tried to change font, but all fonts shown ugly.

I'm using PyCharm 4.5, OS X 10.10.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: @AlexanderKovalev , java version "1.7.0_75"

Answer (score 0):

As per JetBrains, [Apple JDK 1.6 is still the recommended JDK on OS X](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117324#comment=27-706613)

Here is [another useful link to change JDK](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since the question was asked, but I later realize this sudden font change is because PyCharm does not render fonts correctly, not because I used the wrong font.

Here is what I tried and what eventually worked: https://gist.github.com/CrazyCoder/0d9e54f450000d3fb6edcbda6d9788be

Basically, we need to change the starting JDK.